# How to add a compose character to a xkb keyboard layout

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, unicode, xkb, compose-key

I created a custom Ukrainian ISO 9 layout successfully (by redacting `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ua` and several other files), it works and all but it lacks one letter, namely `G with a grave` i.e. 'G̀' (for 'Ґ'), which is absent in Unicode

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "latynka" {

    include "ua(winkeys)"
    name[Group1]= "Ukrainian (Latynka ISO 9)";

    key <TLDE> { [      apostrophe,      asciitilde  ,    dead_acute ] };
    key <AE01> { [               1,         exclam   ] };
    key <AE02> { [               2,        quotedbl  ] };
    key <AE03> { [               3,      numbersign  ] };
    key <AE04> { [               4,        asterisk  ] };
    key <AE05> { [               5,           colon  ] };
    key <AE06> { [               6,           comma  ] };
    key <AE07> { [               7,          period  ] };
    key <AE08> { [               8,       semicolon  ] };
    key <AE09> { [               9,       parenleft  ] };
    key <AE10> { [               0,      parenright  ] };
    key <AE11> { [           minus,      underscore  ] };
    key <AE12> { [           equal,            plus  ] };

    key <AD01> { [               j,               J  ] };
    key <AD02> { [               c,               C  ] };
    key <AD03> { [               u,               U  ] };
    key <AD04> { [               k,               K  ] };
    key <AD05> { [               e,               E  ] };
    key <AD06> { [               n,               N  ] };
    key <AD07> { [               g,               G  ] };
    key <AD08> { [          scaron,          Scaron  ] };
    key <AD09> { [     scircumflex,     scircumflex  ] };
    key <AD10> { [               z,               Z  ] };
    key <AD11> { [               h,               H  ] };
    key <AD12> { [      idiaeresis,      Idiaeresis  ] };
    // key <BKSL> { [          ggrave,          Ggrave  ] };  // does not exist
    // key <BKSL> { [    dead_grave g,    dead_grave G  ] };  // xkb does not allow multiple characters per key press

    key <AC01> { [               f,               F  ] };
    key <AC02> { [          igrave,          Igrave  ] };
    key <AC03> { [               v,               V  ] };
    key <AC04> { [               a,               A  ] };
    key <AC05> { [               p,               P  ] };
    key <AC06> { [               r,               R  ] };
    key <AC07> { [               o,               O  ] };
    key <AC08> { [               l,               L  ] };
    key <AC09> { [               d,               D  ] };
    key <AC10> { [          zcaron,          Zcaron  ] };
    key <AC11> { [     ecircumflex,     Ecircumflex  ] };

    key <AB01> { [     acircumflex,     Acircumflex  ] };
    key <AB02> { [          ccaron,          Ccaron  ] };
    key <AB03> { [               s,               S  ] };
    key <AB04> { [               m,               M  ] };
    key <AB06> { [               t,               T  ] };
    key <AB05> { [               i,               I  ] };
    key <AB07> { [         minutes,          minutes ] };
    key <AB08> { [               b,               B  ] };
    key <AB09> { [     ucircumflex,     Ucircumflex  ] };
    key <AB10> { [           slash,        question  ] };

    key <LSGT> { [          period,           comma  ] };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

Is there any way to add it?

Answer (score 1):

A trick that I've seen used for a Khmer layout was to just assign some unicode codepoint from a range that is not officially defined (i.e. something from (0x10017fb-0x10017ff)) and then add a rule in the "Compose file" to transform that undefined character into your desired output.

As an example, you could define this in the layout:

```
key <BKSL> { [    0x10017fe,    0x10017ff  ] };
```

which by itself would simply output ៾ and ៿, which are undefined unicode characters.

But then you create a "Compose file" in `~/.XCompose` where you can add rules to replace these unicode characters with something else. The compose file would look just like this:

```
<U17fe> : "Ґ"
<U17ff> : "G̀"
```

or whatever you want there. I now mixed the cyrillic with the Latin which is probably not what you want. You can enter there whatever characters you like, even long sequences.

Here is some documentation about compose files: https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/Compose.5.xhtml

There are also some system locations for compose files that should apply for all users for specific locales and so on.
The `~/.XCompose` in your home directory of course only applies to you as a user, and then for all locales.
Probably in your case you could define your mappings in the file `/usr/share/X11/locale/ua/Compose` for the Ukrainian locale.